# why tests.py Task matching query does not exist?

Tags: python, django

### ERROR: test_task_check_success (tasks.tests.TaskCheckTestCase.test_task_check_success)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gns03\OneDrive\바탕 화면\사전과제\tasks\tests.py", line 119, in test_task_check_success
response = self.client.get(self.url, params=self.data1, **header, format='json')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 289, in get
response = super().get(path, data=data, **extra)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 206, in get
return self.generic('GET', path, **r)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 234, in generic
return super().generic(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 609, in generic
return self.request(**r)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 286, in request
return super().request(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 238, in request
request = super().request(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 891, in request
self.check_exception(response)
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 738, in check_exception
raise exc_value
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\OneDrive\바탕 화면\사전과제\tasks\views.py", line 69, in get
task_instance = Task.objects.get(id=request.data.get('task'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gns03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 637, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
tasks.models.Task.DoesNotExist: Task matching query does not exist.

```
views.py

class TaskCheckView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        

        try:
            task_instance = Task.objects.get(id=request.data.get('task'))
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({
                'error_code': status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                'error': '해당 업무를 찾을 수 없습니다.'}, 
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
 
        subtasks_related_to_task = SubTask.objects.filter(task=task_instance)

        subtasks_data = SubTaskSerializer(subtasks_related_to_task, many=True).data
        
        serializer = TaskCheckSerializer(data={
            'task_id': task_instance.id,
            'task_team': ','.join([str(team.id) for team in task_instance.team.all()]),
            'title': task_instance.title,
            'content': task_instance.content,
            'is_complete': task_instance.is_complete,
            'completed_data': task_instance.completed_data,
            'created_at': task_instance.created_at,
            'modified_at': task_instance.modified_at,
            'subtasks': subtasks_data
        })


        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'data': serializer.data, 
                            'status': status.HTTP_200_OK}, 
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        return Response({'error_code': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST}, 
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
serializers.py 

class TaskCheckSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    task_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    task_team = serializers.CharField()
    title = serializers.CharField()
    content = serializers.CharField()
    is_complete = serializers.BooleanField()
    completed_data = serializers.DateTimeField(allow_null=True)
    created_at = serializers.DateField()
    modified_at = serializers.DateField()
    subtasks = SubTaskSerializer(many=True)
```

```
tests.py

class TaskCheckTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.url = '/task/detail/'
        self.user = User.objects.create(email='test1@naver.com', name='팀원1')
        self.user.set_password("qwer1234")
        self.user.save()
        self.token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=self.user)

        self.team1 = Team.objects.create(team='team1')

        self.task = Task.objects.create(title='테스트 제목', content='테스트', create_user=self.user)
        self.task.team.set([self.team1.id])  
        self.subtask = SubTask.objects.create(task=self.task, team=self.team1)
        

        self.data1={
            'task': str(self.task.id)
        }

        self.data2={
            'task': '999'
        }

    def test_task_check_success(self):
        header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f'Token {self.token}'}
        response = self.client.get(self.url, data=self.data1, **header, format='json') 
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have no problem searching the actual task ID on the server, but when I try to search the self.task I created in the test code, I get an error. What is the problem?

I'm not getting a 404 error, the reason I'm getting an error is because I'm clearing the try part of getting the instance and getting the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in your test case lies in the way you are sending the data in the `get` request
in your test case you are passing the data as a dictionary using the `data` parameter which sends the data in the request body however in your view you are trying to retrieve the task ID from the query parameters using `request.data.get('task')`

to fix this you should pass the task ID as a query parameter in the url instead of in the request body

you can modify your test case like this:

```
class TaskCheckTestCase(APITestCase):
     # rest of your code

     def test_task_check_success(self):
        header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f'Token {self.token}'}
        response = self.client.get(f'{self.url}?task={self.task.id}', **header, format='json') 
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK))
```

in this modification I'm appending the task ID to the url as a query parameter and now in your view you can retrieve it using `request.query_params.get('task')`

so your view should looks like this:

```
class TaskCheckView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            task_instance = Task.objects.get(id=request.query_params.get('task'))
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({
                'error_code': status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                'error': '해당 업무를 찾을 수 없습니다.'
            }, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    #rest of your code
```

this should resolve the issue.

I hope this helps you.